# Aspose.Pdf can't find its license file

Tags: vb.net, aspose, aspose.pdf

I have this code in a PDF generation method:

```
Dim license As license = New license
License.SetLicense(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "bin", "Aspose.Pdf.lic"))
```

I also tried simply:

```
Dim license As license = New license
License.SetLicense("Aspose.Pdf.lic")
```

I verified that the license file exists at the above path, but I still get this error:

> Cannot find license 'C:\Users\MyUsername\source\repos\MyApp\Src\MyProject\bin\Aspose.Pdf.lic'.

If the license file is there (and it does appear to be a legitimate XML file, not just a placeholder), why is it not being found?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to give the IIS_IUSRS user group on my PC "full control" permission to the license file. I'm not sure why Aspose.Pdf needs to be able to *write* the license file, not just read it, but that seems to have worked.